# Como puedo hacer que se bloquee un "mat-chip" al clickearlo? (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Estoy intentando bloquear un "mat-chip" que tengo dentro de una tabla, luego de hacer click en él. Necesito que, una vez clickeado el mat-chip, este no pueda volver a ser clickeado. Estuve intentando varias formas de hacerlo, pero ninguna me ha funcionado aún. Hasta ahora tengo este código en el HTML:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="opciones">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Opciones </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let t">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="5%">
        <mat-chip-list>
          <mat-chip [disabled]="t.disabled" cdkDrag (click)="llamarTurno(t)" color="primary" selected>
            <mat-icon>phone</mat-icon>  Llamar
          </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

En el TS tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por consola veo esto, al consultar los turnos de la tabla en tiempo real:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría hacer que esto funcione bien?

Comment: A que te refieres bloquear ?. y que quieres conceguir al hacer click en el.

Comment: Hola @TomaszVizaint me refiero a que no pueda volver a usarse una vez clickeado. Yo cuando le hago click, llamo a un nuevo turno, y necesito que no se pueda re-llamar el turno, sino que solo se llame una sola vez, y luego se bloquee ese botón/mat-chip.

Comment: Si los datos en esta tabla viene de una base de datos, yo añadiria una columna más que indica si el record es editable o no y suponemos este caso, al hazer clic en en el mat.chip actualiza el record por valor true o false si es otro caso necesito más info sobre que ocurre  cuando "llamas al turno".

Comment: Gracias @TomaszVizaint me sirvio tu aporte!! saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cada objeto de la colección puedes agregarle una propiedad `disabled` que se encargará de guardar el estado del objeto.

```
export class ChipsDragDropExample {
  
  vegetables: any[] = [
    { name: "apple", disabled: false },
    { name: "banana", disabled: false },
    { name: "strawberry", disabled: false },
    { name: "orange", disabled: false },
    { name: "kiwi", disabled: false },
    { name: "cherry", disabled: false }
  ];

  eventoClick(vegetable: any) {
    vegetable.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

En la vista se enlaza el valor de la propiedad `disabled` con el atributo disabled del chip.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let vegetable of vegetables">
    <td>
      <mat-chip class="example-box" [disabled]="vegetable.disabled" cdkDrag
      (click)="eventoClick(vegetable)">
        {{vegetable.name}}
      </mat-chip>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

En el click la función `eventoClick` recibe el objeto y cambia su propiedad `disabled` a true y eso bloquea el chip.

El ejemplo fue adaptado de los ejemplos de Angular Material.

Puedes verlo en vivo aquí: [Disable chips on click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foa8kg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-drag-drop-example.html)

**Actualización.**

Parece que al deshabilitar el chip el evento click siempre se ejecuta, en la función `llamarTurno` agregué una validación para que no entre si el turno ya está deshabilitado.

```
llamarTurno(turno: any) {
    if (turno.disabled) return;
```

Agrego ejemplo nuevo con una estructura de código más cercana a la que usas.

[Disable chip on click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foa8kg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-drag-drop-example.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos por tu respuesta, probé el demo y funciona genial, hace lo que yo necesito. Pero cuando lo quise implementar tuve problemas, no se me cambia el atributo disabled! Edite la pregunta para agregarle imágenes, para ver si podes encontrar cual es mi error. Desde ya, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos por fin pude terminar de hacer eso!! Me sirvió mucho tu aporte!! Gracias, saludos!