# FOR con API solo toma el primer valor del array Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, bucle-for, condiciones

tengo el siguiente problema:

Lo que hago es llamar al servicio y el "response" me devuelve los objetos a manejar. Así como se ve:

```
fillColaboradores(){
  let payload = {
    zonas: this.zonas.toString(),
  }
  this.perfilesService.getColaboradores(payload, this.helper.getHeaders())
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.passArray=response;
```

todo bien hasta allí. Resulta que ese array tiene una propiedad llamada "veces" osea **this.passArray.veces**
la cual me da un número, ese numero yo necesito que cuando sea 1 haga una cosa y cuando sea mayor otra, entonces lo tengo asi:

```
      for (let i = 0; i < this.passArray.length; i++) {
        console.log("En el índice '" + i + "' hay este valor: " +
            this.passArray[i].veces);
        console.log("para tracking" + this.passArray[i].enTracking);
        if (this.passArray[i].veces == 1) {
          console.log("entro en el igual a uno??");
          this.divControl = false;

        } else {
          console.log("entro en el mayor??");
          this.divControl = true;
        }
      }

    }

  },
  err =>{
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.errorModal.show();
    console.error("error", err)
  });
}
```

Esto me provoca muchos issues:

- En la primer carga del servicio solo recorre una vez el array y no los demás índices.
- Hasta que doy clic en el botón que activa la función, si hace el recorrido completo y me muestra si entro al ==1 o no, peroooo el icono que debe desaparecer/aparecer sigue siendo verdadero.
- La variable divControl que controla un icono que debe aparecer o desaparecer dependiendo del número, siempre sale como true (osea aparece).
  Les dejo el elemento que debe desaparecer:

  ```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="arrow">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div *ngIf="divControl">
          <i class="bbva-coronita_unfold" mat-button href="javascript:void(0)" 
            (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"                 
            (click)="openCollapse(expandedElement, element)"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  ```

Espero no sea mucho texto, y puedan ayudarme. Lo que quiero es que haga el recorrido y por cada elemento sepa si mostrar o no el elemento dependiendo del **this.passArray.veces**

Gracias

Comment: Entiendo que hay una tabla en la cual hay una columna dónde se muestra un ícono que debe desaparecer dependiendo del estado de `divControl` y `divControl` es una variable en el componente. Es correcto?

Comment: **divControl** está tomando el valor de la última iteración. **divControl** debería ser un arreglo o se puede agregar la propiedad a los elementos del arreglo.

Comment: Si @Lobos es correcto, lo que mencionas.

Comment: Para que funcione, `divControl` debe ser una propiedad de `element`. Así cada fila tendrá su propio `divControl` para evaluar si mostrar o no el ícono. Puedes revisar esta pregunta que es un caso muy parecido https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401671/como-puedo-hacer-que-se-bloquee-un-mat-chip-al-clickearlo-angular/401724#401724

Comment: Damian, gracias por la ayuda. Aclaro que divControl es solo la variable que deberia desaparecer el "icono" el detalle es que a pesar de tener una condición este sigue apareciendo siempre no solo cuando es mayor que uno pareciendo que solo toma el ultimo valor de la iteracion.

Comment: @Lobos podrías ser un poquito mas especifico a lo que te refieres? un ejemplo o algo por favor. Supongo que seria con un viewchild? o un elementById.

Comment: Revisa el enlace que te compartí. Es un caso muy parecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes mapear la respuesta para agregar la propiedad `divControl` a cada elemento del arreglo, si la propiedad `veces` es diferente a 1, `divControl` será true.

```
.subscribe(response => {
      this.passArray = response.map(e => {
           // agregar propiedad divControl
           e['divControl'] = e.veces != 1;
           return e;
       });
  }
```

Luego en la vista se evalúa la propiedad `divControl` del objeto `element`:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="arrow">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <div *ngIf="element.divControl">
        <i class="bbva-coronita_unfold" mat-button href="javascript:void(0)" 
          (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"                 
          (click)="openCollapse(expandedElement, element)"></i>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

De esa forma cada fila tiene su propio `divControl`.

Comment: Gracias @Lobos lo he probado y al parecer es correcto, no sabia que debia asignar a cada "row" su elemento que era por eso que siempre lanzaba true en todos. Más que ayudarme me has enseñado. :D.